# autohotkey launch apps on specific monitors

Tags: autohotkey, multiple-monitors

I'm fairly new to AHK, but have already done some research on this and haven't found a good answer.   I would like to be able to launch an application maximized on a specific monitor.  I think the current best practice is to Run the app and then use WinMove to position.

Currently I have a three panels in the following configuration:  Left (1680x1050), Middle (1920x1080), Right (1920x1080).

The logic to Run and WinMove seems straightforward, but since I have different resolutions and I would like to Run the apps maximized I'm at a loss for how to script this out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, thats about right.

What I would do is `Run`, then `WinMove` horizontally to the correct monitor, then `WinMaximize`